# How to list all volumes using netapp api and java?

Tags: java, netapp

I want to list all volumes using netapp api and Java.
I am using following code:

```
public void VolName() {

ApiRunner runner = new ApiRunner(ApiTarget.builder()

.withHost(host).withUserName(user).withPassword(pass)
        .withTargetType(TargetType.FILER).useHttp().build());

VolumeListInfoIterStartRequest volListReq = new VolumeListInfoIterStartRequest();

Iterator<VolumeInfo> volumeIter = runner.iterate(volListReq, 20);

VolumeInfo volume = null;
while(volumeIter.hasNext()) {
    volume = volumeIter.next();
    System.out.println("Sample 1: " + volume.getName());

}

}
```

In this code I get error at `volume.getName()`, if I used `volume.getVolumeName()` it returns `null`.

How do I get volume information using netapp api and Java?

Answer (score 0):

There is probability of   `volumeIter.hasNext()` returns false so `volume` will be null.
If `volumeIter.hasNext()` returns false you should return null value.
As you want to return list you should add `VolumeInfo` in `list`

Comment: But I get result of 'volume.getBlockType()' result as '64 bit'